# Error inserting scandic letters into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, collation

I'm trying to insert web addresses to my database that contain scandic letters, for example:

> ÄÖäöÅå

I'm using:

- Opensuse 13.2 64bit Linux and MariaDB.
- MySQL Server version: 5.5.44-MariaDB openSUSE package
- PHP Version is 5.4.20

When I try to insert, I get this error message:

> Incorrect string value: '\xC4HK\xD6.

This query confirms that the character set and collation is set correctly:

```
if (mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci")) {
    echo "Character set OK !";
}
```

My MySQL query works for everything except URLs that contain scandic letters:

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`address`) VALUES ('$URL')")){
    $insertCount++;
    echo "<br> insertcount = ".$insertCount."<br>";
} else {
    echo "MySQLerror = ".mysql_error()."<br>"; // Show MySQLerror
```

This is MySQL info from MariaDB, showing that everything is set to `utf8mb4`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

How can I correctly insert scandic letters?

---

### Edit

@Monty: These are my database settings:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%colla%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%charac%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                        |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                       |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                      |
| character_set_system     | utf8                         |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mariadb/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

---

### Edit

@Rick James: This what I got back :

`MariaDB [db]> SHOW CREATE TABLE table;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| table | CREATE TABLE table (
  addr varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (addr),
  UNIQUE KEY addr (addr)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT='List'     |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)`

MariaDB [db]>

Comment: Have a look through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: +Jay Blankhard I have not got that far yet that i can prevent SQL injections, but i will do that as soon as i get this thing solved. Thanks mate.

Comment: Have you verified that your PHP file is saved as utf-8?

Comment: Mate, sorry for the late answer, but it was. I'm in the whole new level with my script now and I have all of you here to thank for it mates :)))

Comment: Mates I just hope that I can someday help someone even close as much as all of You have helped me with my PHP project

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Verify that the tables where the data is stored have the utf8 character set:

```
SELECT
  `tables`.`TABLE_NAME`,
  `collations`.`character_set_name`
FROM
  `information_schema`.`TABLES` AS `tables`,
  `information_schema`.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS `collations`
WHERE
  `tables`.`table_schema` = DATABASE()
  AND `collations`.`collation_name` = `tables`.`table_collation`
;
```

check your database settings:

```
show variables like '%colla%';
show variables like '%charac%';
```

Change utf-8 to utf8_general_ci

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I most humbly thank you for your answer, mate, but i used utf8 before i converted everything to utf8mb4 and it did not work either

Comment: I tried to save 'ÄÖäöÅå' in mysql version 5.0.11-dev. Its inserting. If you are using PHP then you can use htmlspecialchars(); just before inserting into db. Before render use html_entity_decode(); OR you can use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Ok thanks a lot mate I'll try it and i'll let you know how it goes

Comment: I tried $URL = htmlspecialchars($URL); just before inserting and it did render $URL empty when there was scandic letter(s) included.

Answer (score 0):

C4 and D6 are latin1 hex for Ä and Ö.

Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what `CHARACTER SET` is set for the column in question.  I suspect it is incorrectly `latin1`.

And, yes, you must switch away from `mysql_*` interface.

Comment: Looks like there is not any character set set for that column, only collation. Please see my edit. Is it possible that this behavior is caused by that ?

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET` is inherited from the table, namely `utf8mb4`.  Now to scratch my head -- you have it correct, yet there is still a problem.

Comment: mysql_* does not support charsets; mysqli_* does.  [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.overview.html).